# Converting DATE to INT in Infopath

Tags: infopath

convert MM-DD-YYYY TO MMDDYYYY infopath

so for example date: 05-05-2011 would be 05052011 in Info path?

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`number(concat(substring(string(.), 1, 4), substring(string(.), 6, 2), substring(string(.), 9, 2)))`
`string(.)` will convert the date field into a string on the format yyyy-mm-dd. I have written this rule in the text change of the date field, that's why . is used, you can replace the . with the XPath to your field.